# Mock injected SessionContext

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, sessioncontext

I'm injecting SessionContext as a resource to an EJB (implementing container managed transactions):

```
@Stateless(name = "XXX", mappedName = "PPP-MMM-CCC")
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class Xxx implements ItsRemoteInterface {
   @Resource
   private SessionContext sctx;
   ....
}
```

My unit tests are failing because "sctx" is null while they're running (**NullPointerException**). So the only way I've figured to fix this is to create a FakeSessionContext class that implements SessionContext which then I can use during the test.

```
instance = new Xxx();
sessionContextResourceField = Xxx.class.getDeclaredField("sctx");
sessionContextResourceField.setAccessible(true);
sessionContextResourceField.set(instance, new FakeInitialContext());
```

But before I do that, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way? Other than creating a FakeSessionContext class? Something like a factory class?

In case of interest, I'm using jUnit 4.10 and jmockit 0.999.15.

Comment: Yes. Use your mocking framework and ask it to create a fake session context for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jmockit to create a mock version of the session context for you, and use jmockit's version of "when... return" statements to ensure the mock context returns the values you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

for the benefit of others, this is how it's done in jmockit:

```
sessionContextResourceField.set(instance, 
            new MockUp<SessionContext>() {
                @Mock boolean getRollbackOnly() { return false; }
            }.getMockInstance());
```

Although in my case it wasn't necessary to Mock getRollbackOnly (which I use in the code) I did it anyway in case in future the behaviour changes.