# Mockito: Inject mock SessionContext

Tags: java, tdd, ejb-3.0, mockito

Testing EJB3s using Mockito.  I am trying to figure out how to inject a mock SessionContext without changing access.

The SessionContext is injected via `@Resource` as follows:

```
@Resource
protected void setSessionContext(SessionContext sessionContext)
{
    this.sessionContext = sessionContext;
}
```

I did read the following answer showing how to do this with jmockit: [Mock injected SessionContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628354/mock-injected-sessioncontext)

Is there a way to do the same in Mockito?

Also, I read the following answer regarding Mockito and private member variables that implies that the code should be refactored (setter method or constructor parameter): 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995712

Change `setSessionContext` to public feels wrong, changing the application code in order to make it testable with a mocking framework when `SessionContext` really should not be available for setting outside the EJB and its descendants.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you in advance.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Whitebox.setInternalState, which uses reflection to assign the variable inside your object.

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(target, field, value)
```

target - the target object 
field - string name of the field, "sessionContext" in your case
value - the mock SessionContext.